# Android Application Web View Back Button

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a web application that works well but I cannot get the back button to function in the web view.  Please see code:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class extends Activity
{
    final Activity activity = this;


    WebView WebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String     description, String failingUrl)
            {
            // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (WebView != null && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && WebView.canGoBack()) {
        WebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

The application runs but when the back button is pressed it still exits the application.  I am also wanting to add the ability to use a html mailto tag with the application.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Include a null check to see if WebView is null before invoking methods on it.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (WebView != null && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && WebView.canGoBack()) {
    WebView.goBack();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Tried it an ran the app.  When the back button is pressed I get the android force close error and it exits the app.  This happened with both ways to try and resolve the back button.

Comment: What does LogCat tell you about the crash. It should give a specific error. I also updated my code. Make sure you run it with the if check.

Comment: I re-ran the code. Still received the error when using back button. Log said this:  10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
I ran in debug mode and the back button didnt even give an error.  It just froze the app.

Comment: Alright do you any logs you could show. The error is from somewhere else; not in the code above.

Comment: 10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... java.lang.NullPointerException 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at com.webvientest.webvientest.onKeyDown(webvientest.java:59) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at android.view.KevEvent.dispatch(KevEvent.java:1042) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2068) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at corn android internal policy irnpl PhoneUindo'$DecorVie' .dispatchKeyEuent(PhoneUindcv.

Comment: 10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

Comment: 10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
10-25 20:17... E 3778 Andro... at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: You have a null pointer in onKeyDown(). I updated my code with your current setup and have placed a null check in the if statement.

Comment: I used the code with the null check.  I got an error saying "-this method must return a type boolean.-overides android app activity on keydown."  I did it like this:

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (WebView != null && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && WebView.canGoBack()) {
        WebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

Comment: added return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event;   Cleared the error and app runs but when you hit back button in app it exits the application but without an error.

Comment: i figured it out.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me. What is the exact behavior you are hoping to achieve from the back button?

What currently happens when you run the application and press the back button?

Edit, Oh I see what is happening.

You are trying to override onKeyDown() inside your onCreate(). onKeyDown() and onCreate() are both methods of Activity, thus you cannot declare one inside the other.

Try your code like this:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class DealJargon extends Activity {
final Activity activity = this;


    WebView WebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
    }




        WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                   activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

        });

        WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String      description, String failingUrl){
                 // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });


  }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && WebView.canGoBack()) {
        WebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Anytime you get some kind of compile error that has something to do with a brace it is likely that you are trying to declare a method inside the declaration of another method. Or something similar.

Comment: Eclipse if giving me an error to delete token "}" on the closing bracket after:  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); When I delete it says the code after is unreachable.  I wanted the back button to function like a back button in a web browser bringing up previous pages.  I have not been able to run the program since I added the code for the back button.

Comment: It fixed the error and the application runs like normal.  When the back button is pressed an android error comes up, "stopped unexpectedly-Force Close".

Comment: edit your question and include the stack trace that you get when the exception is thrown.

Comment: Edited the question but I am not getting the error with the code now.  The back button exits the app like it did before adding the keyevent code.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @zef99 what did you ultimately do to fix your problem?